# Query data json in PG with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg

I have a ATable ( id, value ) with value type is `json`

```
id | value
--------------------------------------------------
1  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [283, 237, 238] }
2  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [283, 234, 545, 23] }
3  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [98, 56, 2] }
4  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [28345, 100, 333, 987] }
```

I wrote `ATable.where("value->>'user_ids' LIKE ?", "%283%")`

Results:

```
id | value
--------------------------------------------------
1  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [283, 237, 238] }
2  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [283, 234, 545, 23] }
4  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [28345, 100, 333, 987] }
```

Expecting result:

```
id | value
--------------------------------------------------
1  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [283, 237, 238] }
2  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [283, 234, 545, 23] }
```

I try `ATable.where("value->>'user_ids' LIKE In (?)", "283")` but not working

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not a PG expert but the problem with using `"%283%"` is that it will match any number containing those digits. That’s why the row with id 4 is returned (28345).

Try the `@>` operator in conjunction with `->`:

```
ATable.where("value->'user_ids' @> ?", '[283]')
```

[Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)

Not sure this should be tagged as a Rails question, definitely not as a Ruby question.

Comment: Thanks for supporting. But it's not working for me. `Caused by PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: json @> unknown. HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Try casting `user_ids` to jsonb: `ATable.where("value->'user_ids'::jsonb @> ?", '[283]')`

Comment: @LihnNguyen you just need to change it to `ATable.where("value->'user_ids' @> ?", '283')` [Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4U3erWZ9oknVc9GNc8ckSF/0)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a good reason for choosing the PG JSON column type. But since questions like this are asked regularly on SO, let me suggest that the design of your table could be signficantly improved to facilitate your query.

It appears that you are aggregating all the model information into a single column. A much more typical design, for relational databases, and for a Rails app would be a table that has columns `start` and `end`. The relationships to the `users` table would be contained by a reference column within the `users` table.

So if the table is called `preferences`, the `users` table would have a `preference_id` column. The ActiveRecord models would have associations `has_many :users` in the `Preference` model and `belongs_to :preference` in the `User` model.

Finally, you can execute your query "the Rails way". If you want to retrieve the preferences of the user with id=283, it's just `User.find(283).preferences`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much @DennisHackethal, @engineersmnky and @LesNightingill.
I just want to find and delete `283`. Now, I found the way that delete `item` without find.

After removed:

```
id | value
--------------------------------------------------
1  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [237, 238] }
2  | { 'start': '2023-10-02', 'end': '2023-10-05', user_ids: [234, 545, 23] }
```

But i can run sql like that

```
def delete_item(item_ids)
  query_where = item_ids.map.with_index { |p, index| "x.el <> :el_#{index}" }.join(" AND ")
  query = <<-SQL 
    UPDATE atables
    SET value = jsonb_set(to_jsonb (value), '{user_ids}', (
      SELECT jsonb_agg(el)
      FROM jsonb_array_elements_text((value ->> 'user_ids')::jsonb) AS x (el)
        WHERE #{query_where}))
  SQL
 
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [query, { parse(item_ids) }]))
end

def parse(item_ids)
  item_ids.map.with_index { |p, index| { "el_#{index}".to_sym => p } }.inject(&:merge)
end

Call: 
item_ids = ["283"]
delete_item(item_ids)
```